# Show that if $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_k= -\infty$, then $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{x_k} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Show that if $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_k= -\infty$, then $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{x_k} = 0$

I understand this intuitively because if $x_k$ is an infinity large negative number, $1$ over that number would be infinitely small and closer and closer to $0$ from the left. However, I'm having trouble putting that into proof form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hypotheses means that for every $M<0$ there is $K_0$ such that $x_k<M$ for every $k\geq K_0$.

On the other hand, you need to show that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $K_1$ such that $|1/x_k|<\varepsilon$ for all $k\geq K_1$.

So, for $\varepsilon>0$, we set $M=-1/\varepsilon$, therefore there is $K_0$ such that $x_k<-1/\varepsilon$ for all $k\geq K_0$, thus $|1/x_k|<\varepsilon$. Hence, $K_1=K_0$ works!

Answer (score 0):

Let $y_k = -x_k$.  If $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k = -\infty$, then $\lim_{k \to \infty} y_k = \infty$.  Then for all $M > 0$, there is a $K$ such that $y_k > M$ for all $k > K$.  This says that $\frac{1}{y_k} < \frac{1}{M}$.  You can use that to show that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{y_k}=0$.  Then relate this to $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{x_k}$.